# How to access floating point constants?

Tags: floating-point, constants, rust

How do you access the floating point constants defined in the Rust standard library?

For example, I would like to use the statically defined 1/sqrt(2) for a 64 bit float:

```
use std::f64;
//Float::frac_1_sqrt2(); // use of undeclared module Float
//Float.frac_1_sqrt2(); // unresolved name Float
//f64::frac_1_sqrt2(); // unresolved name f64::frac...
//f64.frac_1_sqrt2(); // unresolved name f64
//1.0f64.frac_1_sqrt2(); // f64 doesn't implement frac_1_sqrt2
//frac_1_sqrt2::<f64>(1.0) // frac_1_sqrt2 unresolved
//frac_1_sqrt2::(1.0f64) // frac_1_sqrt2 unresolved
//f64::frac_1_sqrt2(1.0f64) // frac_1_sqrt2 unresolved
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//Float::frac_1_sqrt2(); // use of undeclared module Float
```

This is about right but you gotta bring `Float` into scope or address it with its absolute path. Next you're gonna need to give it an inference hint so it knows which floating point type's `Float` impl you want. The following works:

```
use std::num::Float;
let x: f64 = Float::frac_1_sqrt2();
println!("{}", x);
```

Comment: The fully explicit syntax is gonna look like `<std::num::Float for f64>::frac_1_sqrt2()` but who knows when that'll get implemented :P

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use the static constants defined in `f64::consts` (and `f32::consts` for the equivalents):

```
use std::f64;

fn main() {
    let a = f64::consts::FRAC_1_SQRT2;
}
```